# How is Average Recall (AR) calculated for an object detection model?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, object-detection

After looking around the internet (including [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.05082), I cannot seem to find a satisfactory explanation of the Average Recall (AR) metric. On the COCO [website](http://cocodataset.org/#detection-eval), it describes AR as: "the maximum recall given a fixed number of detections per image, averaged over categories and IoUs".

What does "maximum recall" mean here?

I was wondering if someone could give a reference or a high level overview of the AR calculation algorithm.

Thanks!